# EJS- add multiple words as value to search bar

Tags: node.js, ejs

I was creating a simple project with `EJS` and `Node.JS` where the client searches for a query on the home page and results are returned on another page, with the search bar still containing the query in it. I run into issues when multiple words are searched for by the user. For example, when the user searches for "Hello World", the relevant results for the query are returned but the search bar on that page only contains the first word of the query i.e. "Hello". Following is a MVP replicating the same problem.

This is the code in `server.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.listen(9900, function(){
    console.log('Server is running')
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('test', {query: "Hello World"})
});
```

And this is the code in `views/test.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>


<div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" value=<%= query %>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

In this case, the search bar only contains the word "Hello", even though the phrase "Hello World" is passed from the server.

I'd appreciate any help on how to get around this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed quotation marks and **>**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" value="<%= query %>">
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just btw, how did you know that quotation marks were required? It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere..

Comment: Also, why did having it without the quotation marks, print only the first word?

Comment: From practice :) EJS is very poor documented :(